# HTML DOM manipulation in Laravel 4

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4

In my app I'm using Laravel 4.1 and I would like to do a more complex modification of html string that was passed by WYSIWYG texarea in html form. I used to work with Symfony 2, where I can do this efficiently with packages like https://github.com/wasinger/htmlpagedom. Is there something similar in Laravel? How could I make wasinger/htmlpagedom package working in Laravel?

Comment: You should be able to add the package to your `composer.json` file along with the depended packages (i.e. `symfony/dom-crawler` & `symfony/css-selector`) and then use it as your normally would, no?

Comment: Just follow the instructions available in the github link you pointed out and it will work the same in Laravel 4.1 as in Symfony 2. And if you want to avoid namespaces, verify the aliases at `app/config/app.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No big deal, I've just added package to composer.json and than I used it in \Wa72\HtmlPageDom\HtmlPageCrawler namespace.